# Getting Data Not Available when using Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, unmanaged-package

I packaged up a Lightning Component and Apex Class with Test Class as a managed package but when I tried installing in another dev org I got the error:

"Data Not Available: The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page."

When I packaged the same component up with the apex classes as an unmanaged package everything worked fine. Anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: Assuming the managed and unmanaged packages have exactly the same components then a possible problem will be the namespace that the managed package introduces.

Comment: Is this an error on install of package? Runtime use of component?